# How to filter duplicates with jq/awk/grep/sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, jq

I have the following which has been piped from jq, I need to print every instance-name that does not contain key-one. For example the command would return instance-name-5 if applied to the below. Should I apply another jq filter or just use grep/awk?

```
"instance-name-1 key-one"
"instance-name-1 instance-template"
"instance-name-1 created-by"
"instance-name-2 key-one"
"instance-name-2 instance-template"
"instance-name-2 created-by"
"instance-name-3 key-one"
"instance-name-3 key-one"
"instance-name-3 instance-template"
"instance-name-3 created-by"
"instance-name-4 key-one"
"instance-name-4 instance-template"
"instance-name-4 created-by"
"instance-name-5 key-two"
"instance-name-5 instance-template"
"instance-name-5 created-by"
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: If `grep` can find something then it can also discard something. Check man pages.

Comment: Please give an example of the input.json

Comment: I'd tend to prefer to just fix your `jq` script to not generate this output in the first place. One certainly *could* write a separate jq script to do the filtering, but it's easier to just take the undesired content out than to clean it up after the fact.

Comment: For instance, I'm **assuming** that before these items were concatenated into a string in jq, they were either different members of an object or different elements in an array. If that's the case, it's less work to deal with the situation *before* they're smooshed together.

Answer (score 1):

> to print every instance-name that does not contain **key-one** ... the
>   command would return **instance-name-5**

Use the following `awk` approach *piping* with `uniq` command:

```
awk '{gsub(/"/, "", $0); if($2 == "key-one") {a[$1]++} if ($2 != "key-one" && !a[$1]){ print $1 }} '  testfile | uniq
```

The output:

```
instance-name-5
```

---

`gsub(/"/, "", $0)` - will replace trailing double quotes

`if($2 == "key-one") {a[$1]++}` - captures all "instance names" which marked with `key-one`

`($2 != "key-one" && !a[$1]){ print $1 }` - prints all "instance names" which are not in the list of ignored(`key-one`) "instance names"

`uniq` - omit repeated lines

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

**Input**

```
$ cat file
"instance-name-1 key-one"
"instance-name-1 instance-template"
"instance-name-1 created-by"
"instance-name-2 key-one"
"instance-name-2 instance-template"
"instance-name-2 created-by"
"instance-name-3 key-one"
"instance-name-3 key-one"
"instance-name-3 instance-template"
"instance-name-3 created-by"
"instance-name-4 key-one"
"instance-name-4 instance-template"
"instance-name-4 created-by"
"instance-name-5 key-two"
"instance-name-5 instance-template"
"instance-name-5 created-by"
```

In current context both will work

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[" ]' '/key-one/{a[$2]}!($2 in a){ print $2; a[$2] }' file
instance-name-5
```

**OR**

```
$ awk -F'[" ]' '/key-one/{a[$2]}!($2 in a) && !seen[$2]++{ print $2}' file
instance-name-5
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F'[" ]' '                     # call awk and set field sep as quote and space
         /key-one/{                # if key-one found in current row/line/record
                   a[$2]           # register instance name in array a
         }
         !($2 in a){               # if instance name does not exists in array a then
                   print $2;       # print instance name
                   a[$2]           # register instance name so that
                                   # you will print only once ( to avoid duplicate )
         }
      '  file
```

**For**

```
awk -F'[" ]' '/key-one/{a[$2]}!($2 in a) && !seen[$2]++{ print $2}' file
```

> `!($2 in a) && !seen[$2]++ {print $2}`

instance name (`$2` as index) does not exists in array `a`, meaning instance name does not contain `key-one` and `!seen[$2]++` second field (as index), that is instance name not printed before then print second field(`$2`).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to tackle this sort of thing with `grep` and chained simple commands just because I can find these text manipulations in old shell scripts and understand and reuse them quickly.  It's also clear what your intermediate data is, so that you can change the behavior to suit your needs easily.

You can do this with `grep`, `cut -f1` to get the first column (with `-d' '` to use spaces as a column delimiter), and `sort -u` or `uniq` to do uniquing.

**All in one, you can do this:**

`grep key-one yourfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u | grep -vf- yourfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq | sed 's/"//g'`

to get:

```
 instance-name-5
```

**Explanations:**

Get the instances that have `key-one`:

`grep key-one yourfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u > delete_these.txt`

This creates delete_these.txt:

```
"instance-name-1
"instance-name-2
"instance-name-3
"instance-name-4
```

Then use the above as a pattern file for `grep`:

`grep -v -f delete_these.txt yourfile.txt`:

```
"instance-name-5 key-two"
"instance-name-5 instance-template"
"instance-name-5 created-by"
```

And if you want to just cut that down to names again:

`grep -v -f delete_these.txt yourfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u`:

```
"instance-name-5
```

You can also use `sed 's/"//g'` to remove quotes at any point.  `grep -f-` reads patterns from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jq, it would make sense to apply the filter using jq.  jq 1.5 supports regular expressions, so you could for example include something like: `..... | select(.key | test("key-one") | not)`

If your jq does not include regex support, then consider upgrading, or using `index` or perhaps `contains` (but check the documentation for how to use these appropriately with your version of jq).